# Xamarin Forms Exrin Framework pushing a container as a Modal?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, exrin

I've been playing with the Exrin Xamarin Forms framework which I'm liking.

I've come to a blocker where I want to push a container as a Modal. Anyone know any tips on how to do this? I can't find any examples, or a best approach on how to push a container as Modal.

Looking at the Exrin code, might have to change `BaseStack.cs`, create a `NavigationModal` `ResultType`, lifestyle so it doesn't affect already in memory containers, etc...?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind Exrin and its Stacks, is that a Modal wouldn't be needed. The only reason for Modals, is for a page that you can't just press back from and sits on top of the existing page.

The recommended approach here, is to create a new Stack and just navigate to that. Then go back to the previous stack once finished. It behaves the same way as a Modal, but you don't need to actually use a Modal.

**Update**

If you must have a Modal, while other ways to support transitions come into play, you can modify your NavigationProxy. Replace the 2 functions below.

```
 public async Task PopAsync()
    {
        if (_page.Navigation.ModalStack.Count > 0)
        {
            var page = _page.Navigation.ModalStack[0];
            _page_Popped(null, new NavigationEventArgs(page));
            await _page.Navigation.PopModalAsync();

        }
        else
            await _page.PopAsync();
    }

    public async Task PushAsync(object page)
    {
        var xamarinPage = page as Page;

        if (xamarinPage == null)
            throw new Exception("PushAsync can not push a non Xamarin Page");

        if (page is ExrinSample.View.AboutView)
            await _page.Navigation.PushModalAsync(xamarinPage);
        else
            await _page.PushAsync(xamarinPage);
    }
```

Of course this is manually referencing a specific page in your proxy. If you wanted to clean that up, you could add some methods in your Stack to list pages that are modal, and use that list to push to modal if needed, rather than directly putting the page names inside the proxy.

Comment: Ah ok, interesting. I'll give you some background on what I want to do. I have a TabbedPage, and one of the Tabs has a floating action button. When that button gets tapped, I need a Modal of a page (or stack, just 1 view is needed), to pop up and take the entire screen (ie hide the tabs, navigation, everything)... and then get popped down when done...

Comment: A new stack, with one page mapped, would be the way to achieve that. Then navigate to that stack. Maybe I also need to look into making the building of a stack quicker and easier, for these types of scenario's.

Comment: Cool that worked. But I really need a modal animation. Do you know any way I can achieve that even if I fork Exrin?

Comment: Just referencing the animation of a MainPage transition, API proposal: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90558/mainpage-animated-transitions